# Carburetor, throttle, airflow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

It is said that the less we open the throttle the speed in a Venturi tube inside the carburetor is slower, thus less reduction in pressure and less fuel is being sucked from float chamber, however, actually if we reduce the area of the tube by closing throttle, according to Bernoulli's theorem, the speed of air in the same tube should increase, shouldn't it?

Comment: How is this different than what you asked here?  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/55961/how-does-the-throttle-position-affect-the-speed-of-airflow-to-the-engine  Which was answered with a nice diagram as well.

Answer (score 2):

The carburetors that I have seen were indeed a venturi of a sort, and they had a butterfly valve on the upstream side of them to control air flow into the "throat" of the carburetor.  When the butterfly valve on top of the carburetor closes, the pressure drop across the butterfly valve goes up.  There is then a lower pressure immediately downstream of the butterfly valve.  The pressure drop from the downstream side of the butterfly valve into the intake manifold is reduced as a result, so the mass air flow rate into the intake manifold goes down and the fuel flow rate goes down.

Regarding the velocity of the air going into the carburetor, when the butterfly valve closes, the air velocity going past the edge of the butterfly valve will no doubt increase because the cross-sectional area available for the air to enter the carburetor goes down when the butterfly valve closes, and the continuity equation will be obeyed because it represents a conservation law.  However, the cross-sectional area of the carburetor throat does not change, so a reduction in air flow into the carburetor means that the air velocity in the carburetor throat goes down, again obeying the continuity equation.